# Trending proof for fairly simple fraction

Tags: fractions

(Please humour the physicist!)

Why does 
$\left(\frac{1-a}{1-a^b}\right) \to \frac{1}{b}$ as $a \to 1$?

This came from a calculation involving flow measurement of gases, and although I can see and compute the answer, I don't understand how this general result occurs.

Comment: L'Hopital rule?

Comment: Welcome to the mystical world of Q Generalizations! (They are quite interesting to play with algebraically!)

Comment: Note that $\forall x\in \mathbb R\forall n\in \mathbb N\left(x^n-1=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\ldots +1)\right)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{a\to1}\dfrac{a^b-1}{a-1}=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{(1+h)^b-1}h$$

Using [Binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), this can be reduced to

$$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{1+bh+O(h^2)-1}h=?$$

Comment: This is even more efficient than L'Hopitals!

Comment: This calculates the derivative of $x\mapsto x^b$ at $x=1$.